# Compilar con Kotlin en VScode

Tags: kotlin, vscode

Instalé el VScode y los plugins necesarios pero me sigue saliendo este mensaje:

**"C:/Program" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.**

**[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.525 seconds**

He cambiado la ruta del compilador en el path de muchas formas y aun nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Parece que no le gusta el espacio que hay en la ruta "Program files".¿Puedes completar la pregunta para especificar qué plugins usas para kotlin y cuál usas para ejecutar el código?

Answer (score 2):

Las variables de entorno son correctas. El problema está en el comando que usas para compilarlo. No sé que plugin estés usando pero debería funcionar si escribes los comandos manualmente.

Para compilar:

```
kotlinc app.kt -d app.jar
```

Para ejecutar:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

Otras alternativas para ejecutarlo:

```
java -classpath app.jar AppKt
java -cp app.jar AppKt
kotlin -classpath app.jar AppKt
kotlin -cp app.jar AppKt
```

Debo mencionar que el IDE recomendado para trabajar con kotlin es IntelliJ IDEA. Es desarrollado por JetBrains que son los mismos que desarrollan el lenguaje y por lo tanto es el que tiene mejor soporte.

Comment: Estos son los 2 plugins que estoy usando : CodeRunner y Kotlin Language

Comment: Disculpa pero soy nuevo en VScode, donde es que tengo que poner los comandos ?

Comment: ahí abajo, en la pestaña terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que definir una nueva variable de entorno
KOTLINC_HOME y asignarle el directorio donde está el compilador:
c:\Prog......\Kotlinc
Ademas añadirlo en el path de ejecución.
%KOTLINC_HOME%\bin

No le valdrá a quien formuló la pregunta, pero habrá otros, como yo , a quienes les ha pasado